# MySQL 5.7 to 8.0.28 Upgrade Warning "Creating indexes larger than 767 bytes"

Tags: mysql

I am upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.28.  My application tests are all passing since performing the upgrade.

The MySql upgrade log contains the following warning:

```
22) Creating indexes larger than 767 bytes on tables with redundant row format might cause the tables to be inaccessible.
    You have one or more tables with redundant row format. Creating an index larger than 767 bytes might cause the table to be inaccessible (only 50 tables are shown).
    More Information:
        https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99791
```

The tables that report this warning are not tables that I created.

```
[table_schema, table_name]
inv,FTS_000000000000006f_DELETED_CACHE - Consider restoring the DB instance from a snapshot creating before upgrading, and change the row_format of the tables to dynamic.
inv,FTS_000000000000006f_00000000000000ed_INDEX_3 - Consider restoring the DB instance from a snapshot creating before upgrading, and change the row_format of the tables to dynamic.
...
inv,FTS_000000000000006f_BEING_DELETED - Consider restoring the DB instance from a snapshot creating before upgrading, and change the row_format of the tables to dynamic.
inv,FTS_000000000000006f_00000000000000ed_INDEX_1 - Consider restoring the DB instance from a snapshot creating before upgrading, and change the row_format of the tables to dynamic.
inv,FTS_000000000000006f_BEING_DELETED_CACHE - Consider restoring the DB instance from a snapshot creating before upgrading, and change the row_format of the tables to dynamic.
```

`inv` is the name of my database.  These FTS tables sort of match the names of tables in the `information_schema.`

At the bottom of https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99791, I see the following message

> Fixed as of the upcoming 8.0.22 release, and here's the proposed
> changelog entry from the documentation team:

Based on this reported fix, is any action likely to be required on my part before I proceed with my upgrade?

Comment: You could just [make sure there are no indexes on columns that may be longer than 767 bytes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293937/how-to-fix-file-format-in-tables-after-upgrade-of-mysql-5-6-mysql-8-0-23-in-a).  That would circumvent the entire issue.

Comment: I'm going through the same exact thing right now, and wonder if you have been able to figure this one out ?

Comment: @Zee, I exported my database with mysqldump and imported the content into a new database.  That has resolved the issue.

Comment: @terrywb, just wondering if you needed to switch any of the existing non-dynamic row_format to be dynamic first? iam upgrading from 5.7 to 8.0.32, got the warning as we have mix of compact and dynamic, but not sure if we need to change anything before moving to version 8 based on this warning?

Comment: @Zee, I did not make that change.